# why is my jersey ClientResponse not empty and yet available returns 0?

Tags: java, http, jersey, byte, arrays

I have this jersey webResource code:

```
   @Override
    public int Foo(long uId, String secretKey, long tileId) {
        int answer = 0;
        String ans;
        try {
            ClientResponse response = webResource
                    // .path("multi-get")
                    .queryParam("reqtype", "tileBatch")
                    .queryParam("protocol", "1")
                    .queryParam("sessionid", String.valueOf(uId))
                    .queryParam("cookie", String.valueOf(secretKey))
                    .queryParam("num", "1")
                    .queryParam("t0", String.valueOf(tileId))
                    .queryParam("v0", "0")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            answer = response.getEntityInputStream().available();

            byte[] byteArray = output.getBytes("UTF-8");
            ans = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

I see `String output = response.getEntity(String.class);` is not empty and yet in `answer = response.getEntityInputStream().available();` then `answer == 0` how come?

If I want to parse the 2 first bytes from binary data into an integer
how can I do this? `(int) byteArray[0]` ?

e.g. `00000000-00010000`

**Edit**

I tried this code:

```
InputStream entityInputStream = response.getEntityInputStream();
            answer = entityInputStream.available();
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            byte[] byteArray = new byte[2];
          //  entityInputStream.reset();

            entityInputStream.read(byteArray);

            String s = new String(byteArray);
```

but yet `byteArray == {0,0}` even though `output` is not empty.

```
output == ....
�*WZDF04x��:w|������6[�!�M���@HH �� �����TQ�W�""$@�Z $(���ұ=��[��� ��d�s�n6K�������{�99��{����$qE48"
```

is my way correct?

Comment: Once you read with `getEntity` the stream becomes empty. The stream is read from to convert to string. The same stream can't be read from twice

Comment: thanks. please post an answer and i'll vote. btw, if I read two bytes how can I parse it to int? e.g. `00000000-00000010` to 4?

Answer (score 1):

> I see `String output = response.getEntity(String.class);` is not empty and yet in `answer = response.getEntityInputStream().available();` then `answer == 0` how come?

When you do `response.readEntity(String.class)`, the input stream is being read from, and clears out the input stream. So your next attempt to retrieve the input stream will return an empty stream.

> If I want to parse the 2 first bytes from binary data into an integer how can I do this?

You can simply wrap the `InputStream` in an `DataInputStream`, and use `DataInputStream.readInt()`. Then you can read the rest of the intput stream, with `response.readEntity(String.class);`. You seem to be trying to read the string, and *then* the int, which doesn't go with the above statement of yours.

Test

```
@Path("/string")
public class StringResource {  
    @GET
    public StreamingOutput getString() {
        return new StreamingOutput(){
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream out) 
                    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
                outStream.writeInt(1234567);
                outStream.writeUTF("Hello World");
            }
        };
    }
}

@Test
public void testMyResource() throws Exception {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource wr = client
            .resource("http://localhost:8080/api/string");
    ClientResponse response = wr.get(ClientResponse.class);

    InputStream is = response.getEntityInputStream();
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    int num = dis.readInt();
    System.out.println(num);    
    System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
    response.close();
}
```

Prints out `1234567` then `Hello World`